# Access VBA - Display table row data in a Msgbox

Tags: vba, row, msgbox

I'm rather new to programing with Access VBA and I've not been able to find out anywhere that could help me with this problem.

I'm working with a table that contains a list of postcode for the London Area. I have a list of 2248 postcodes and for each Postcode I have a Cluster reference. for example

N1 1AS  | A
N16 5DF | F

and so on.

My problem is when I want to display the cluster information. I tried a combo box but there seems to be a limit and stops at about 100 postcodes, I would like to code a command that will trigger once someone has put in a postcode that a message box will pop up and display the cluster of that postcode.

So for example, I type N1 1AS in the Postcode box and it will display A in a message box.

thanks for all your help,

Gareth Jones

Answer (score 0):

Put a button next to the textbox, and the OnClick event would be something like:

```
Dim X as String

X = DLookUp("tblPostcodes", "fldCluster", "fldPostCode = '" & Me.txtPostCode & "'")

msgbox "The Cluster is " & X
```

That might need a little tweaking, but it should get you close.

EDIT: You could put it in the LostFocus event of the textbox, but I'm not a fan of that because if someone decides to click out of the box for some reason it tries to execute the code anyway, and it just feels sloppy.